# Window 8 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wubi, windows-7, windows-8

I have a Lenovo Ideapad laptop. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 along with Windows 7 using WUBI. Now I have upgraded to Windows 8. In the boot menu, it's not showing the Ubuntu OS, even when I have disabled the fast booting option from the Windows 8 boot menu. 
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a WUBI-method, I'm not so sure this Ubuntu-installation survived the upgrade from W7 to W8/

I supose it's better to re-install with the WUBI-method a fresh installation of Ubuntu.